# QuickBooks Desktop Integration

Tags: quickbooks, point-of-sale

I have a task to make a syncing service that can sync the sales records present in the Quick books point of sale into the local database.
How to integrate Quick books desktop point of sale and web application(c#) via web connector?

Code used :
    public string sendRequestXML(string ticket, string strHCPResponse, string 
    strCompanyFileName, 
            string qbXMLCountry, int qbXMLMajorVers, int qbXMLMinorVers) {
            if (Session["counter"] == null) {
                Session["counter"] = 0;
            }
            string evLogTxt="WebMethod: sendRequestXML() has been called by 
    QBWebconnector" + "\r\n\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"Parameters received:\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"string ticket = " + ticket + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"string strHCPResponse = " + strHCPResponse + 
    "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"string strCompanyFileName = " + 
    strCompanyFileName + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"string qbXMLCountry = " + qbXMLCountry + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"int qbXMLMajorVers = " + 
    qbXMLMajorVers.ToString() + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"int qbXMLMinorVers = " + 
    qbXMLMinorVers.ToString() + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"\r\n";

```
        ArrayList req=buildRequest();
        string request="";
        int total = req.Count;
        count=Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"]);

        if(count<total) {
            request=req[count].ToString();
            evLogTxt=evLogTxt+ "sending request no = " + (count+1) + "\r\n";
            Session["counter"] = ((int) Session["counter"]) + 1;
        }
        else{
            count=0;
            Session["counter"]=0;
            request="";
        }
        evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"\r\n";
        evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"Return values: " + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt=evLogTxt+"string request = " + request + "\r\n";
        logEvent(evLogTxt);
        return request;
    }
```

It is creating log in the end, how will i fetch the data from the QBPOS?

Comment: You are going to need to post WAY more details. What programming language? What research have you done so far? Post your code. Post your logs. There's a ton of resources out there you can find by searching Google, so where are you stuck?

Comment: I am using C# programming language. I have installed SDK from the intuits website and connected the Quickbooks with my SDK. Now, i am stuck at creating a service which can connect with my QB POS.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code. Post what you've done so far.

Comment: I am using QBPOS SDK, in the step 3 when i click begin session it says couldnot connect to database. What database is it talking about? Currently i am using the sample code that comes with the SDK, i am using QWCPOSWebService code.                                                                          Code is : public string sendRequestXML(string ticket, string strHCPResponse, string strCompanyFileName, 
   string qbXMLCountry, int qbXMLMajorVers, int qbXMLMinorVers) {
From where i will get the parameter values?

Comment: Please help me out with how can i connect QBPOS with my code.

Comment: Post your code. We can not help you without you posting your code in the question.